# How to print black & white from Microsoft Edge

Tags: printing, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I really want to like Windows 10.  I can't believe I have to ask the following question:

How do I print black and white from Microsoft Edge?

The new interfaces are neat and readable and everything, but color options are neither in the basic settings nor the advanced settings.  Bing returns results for printing in Office.  These days Google's results are proving just as useless.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check your printer options

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'm familiar with changing the settings for a printer manually via the control panel.  This is the work around I used.  However, this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: I meant in the printer advanced properties. There is usually an option in there somewhere to choose color or black and white.

Comment: Yes, I am used there being an option as well.  However, as stated in the original question, this option is not existent in the advanced options (in this case referred to as "More Settings").

Comment: Have you looked for a Windows 10 update for your printer software?

Comment: @DavidPostill - After some research, HP asserts that the basic drivers included in Windows 10 are all I need.  The only other software they have is the Print Suite, which I do not need.

Comment: If you continue with the print, what happens? Does it start printing or do you get any other windows/options?

Comment: @MC10 - Selecting "OK" prints the document with the selected options.  AKA - it prints in color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **More Settings** there should be an **Output options** section. Under you should see **Color mode**.

[image: Color setting]

I get a **Monochrome** setting. This is *printer specific* so if you are trying to print to XPS or PDF, it will not have this option.

[image: Monochrome]

**Edit:** If you do not see these settings, it is most likely a printer driver issue. I would wait to see if the manufacturers update their drivers for Windows 10 specifically.

Comment: I have an HP Photosmart C4580 - I do not have this option under More Settings.

Comment: The only option in the Output options area is Document Binding.  Installing Office now to test printing from Word.  Printing from Wordpad still uses the old printer dialogue, allowing me to choose greyscale.

Comment: MS Word provides a "Printer Preferences" link that opens up the old dialogue box and allows me to choose greyscale.  It does not seem to share the new dialogue interface of MS Edge.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct as it seems that this is the correct workflow I'm looking for.  It seems likely that I am missing this option due to the printer driver.

Answer (score -1):

You can print to PDF or XPS and then print from that in your program of choice, using your driver of choice.  If you find that Adobe Reader can't put out in monochrome either, then your problem is probably a bad driver.  An older driver might work better for you, or a generic one.

Comment: " realize this isn't what you asked for" - This is a comment and shouldn't exist in your answer, just focus on answering the question, leave the commentary to the comment section.

Comment: I realize this isn't what you asked for, but Microsoft has been very slow at introducing features to Edge. They want to avoid the bloat of IE, and the easiest way to do that is to not give people the enormous list of what they want. Case in point : It took them until the Anniversary Update to put in the "Don't close while downloading files" feature.